# Whats the name of this plant

Tags: identification, houseplants

[image]

it has dark green leaves with tiny white spots on it and has berries too, small green ones which eventually turn dark red.

Comment: Is this an indoor plant or growing outdoors?  Where in the world is it growing?

Comment: And how tall/wide is it?

Answer (score 2):

This is possibly Matrimony Vine (*[Lycium barbarum](https://gobotany.newenglandwild.org/species/lycium/barbarum/)*). The fruit colour fits, the white spots, vining and glossy leaves. In the post photo the leaves are cuneate (wedge shaped, narrower at base) but this does not always seem to be so from other references. Grows wild in New England, but might be grown as a houseplant due to sentimental reasons.